# How to handle disconnections/reconnections with asyncio.Protocol?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to set up an app that "glues" together 2 connections. I am trying to use async stuff properly.

Here's how I did so far:

```
import asyncio

class Protocol1(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        # should I do something here?
    # some stuff

class Protocol2(asyncio.Protocol):
    # some other stuff

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    transport1, protocol1 = await loop.create_unix_connection(lambda: Protocol1(), path=SOCKET_PATH)

    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()  # is this sound?

    transport2, protocol2 = await loop.create_connection(lambda: Protocol2(), host=HOST, port=PORT)

    protocol2.procotol1 = protocol1  # maybe this is ugly too?
    await on_con_lost
    print("Both connection lost?")

asyncio.run(main())
```

I would like to understand how to handle reconnections in case one of the 2 connections goes down. Can you point me out in the right direction?